# SQL Server 2016 Always Encrypted and AlwaysOn readable secondary connection error

Tags: sql-server, alwayson, sql-server-2016

I've used Always Encrypted in SQL 2016 to encrypt the data in a few columns of a table in my application. Always encrypted appears to be set up correctly, because I can see the encrypted data in SSMS and the decrypted data in my application.

My application connects to an AlwaysOn availability group for it's database. I can run queries against the primary database without any errors. As soon as I try to run a query against the active read only secondary, I get the following error:

SQL Server instance in use does not support column encryption.

Given that the query I run against the secondary doesn't even go against the table with encrypted data, I'm assuming the problem is related to the fact I added this to my read only connection string:

Column Encryption Setting=Enabled

Does anyone know if this is an issue, and if so how do I resolve it? Is my only option to only query against the primary when accessing encrypted data and remove that option from my read only connection string?

Thanks in advance!